# Array() = range().value

Tags: excel, vba

I saw `array() = range().value` in an example and I'm trying to understand how it works.

```
Sub test()
Dim arr() As Variant

arr() = Range("E5:E7").Value
For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
    Debug.Print arr(i)
Next i

End Sub
```

First, above code is giving me `subscript out of range` error. How come ? Second, what part of the documentation would let me know how `array() = range().value` would play out without testing it ? My hypothesis is that it will go through the cells from the top left to the bottom right and add them to the array. How can I confirm that though ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good read for you: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx

The reason you're getting "out of range" is because it returns a 2 dimensional array.

Your line of code `For i = 0 To UBound(arr)` should be `For i = 1 To UBound(arr,1)`

Also, the array starts at 1, so don't use the 0 `For i = 1 to UBound(arr, 1)`

Your corrected code would be:

```
Sub Test()

Dim arr() as Variant
arr = Range("E5:E7")
For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
    MsgBox (arr(i, 1))
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Selected this one as an answer due to the informative link on the topic. Thank you every one.

Comment: Why do I get a `Type Mismatch` if I change the range to `Range("E5")`?

Comment: If the range is a single cell, it returns a single value instead of a range. Only ranges containing multiple cells return an array. You can determine this using `If Range("E5").Cells.CountLarge = 1` and program accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I see two issues with your code.  The first is that you start i at 0, but arrays in Excel begin at index 1.  Instead of `For i = 0` you can use `For i = LBound(arr)` like you use `UBound(arr)` or just start it at 1.

Second, and more importantly, an array of cells has both columns and rows.  When you read a range into a variant array, you get a two-dimensional result (rows and columns) and not a one-dimensional result as you seem to be expecting.

Try this:

```
Sub test()
        Dim arr() As Variant
        Dim i As Long, j As Long

        arr() = Range("E5:E7").Value
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
                For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
                        Debug.Print arr(i, j)
                Next j
        Next i
End Sub
```

If you want to get just the values of the cells into a one dimensional array, you can do that by using the `Transpose` function, like this:

```
arr() = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("E5:E7").Value)
```

If you do this, the array is now one-dimensional and you can iterate through it like you were trying to.

```
arr() = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("E5:E7").Value)

For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    Debug.Print arr(i)
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

It's basically loading the cell values of E5 - E7 into an array. But it is going to be two dimensional. So you will need Debug.Print arr(i, 1)

```
Sub test()
Dim arr() As Variant

arr() = Range("E5:E7").Value
For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    Debug.Print arr(i, 1)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting a `Type Mismatch` error with the code. Edit: that's because I changed the range to `Range("E5")`.

Comment: You will need to start at 1 For i = 1